# Trying to make a symbolic link to a Powershell script

Tags: script, powershell, mklink

I'm trying to create a symbolic link with mklink through a Powershell script to a Powershell script on a remote server. this link should come on the desktop of all users.

> if(!(test-path -path \$hostname\c$\Users)) {     Copy-Item -Path
>   "\dsfpad\Nagios\Nagios_Downtime\Nagios -
>   Schedule Downtime.lnk" -Destination "\$hostname\c$\Documents and
>   Settings\All Users\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime.lnk" } else {
>     $s=New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostname    Enter-PSSession $s
>     Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c mklink
>   "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime.lnk"
>   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file
>   c:\Nagios\Nagios_Downtime_Window_NRDP.ps1"}       exit-pssession
>     remove-pssession $s }

I get symbolic link created for C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime.lnk <<===>> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\po
wershell.exe -file c:\Nagios\Nagios_Downtime_Window_NRDP.ps1

But when I try to execute the link on a server, it doesn't work. looking at the Target of the link, therer seems to be no target...

Any tips / ideas?

Comment: it seems when i dont't use C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file in the target, I do get a target in the lnk file, but it does not execute the script...

Comment: Creating a symlink requires admin level on windows, and the link target must exist. There are multiple types of them, one is similar to hardlink, one is to bind-mounts, and the third is the normal symlink. You know: hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

This post is quite old, but I would just create another .ps1 file that calls the requested .ps1 file:

In your case instead of

`& cmd /c mklink "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime.lnk" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file c:\Nagios\Nagios_Downtime_Window_NRDP.ps1"`

I would just use:

`"& c:\Nagios\Nagios_Downtime_Window_NRDP.ps1" | Out-File "c:\temp\C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime_lnk.ps1"`

If you cannot execute the file you can use **-ExecutionPolicy Bypass** (see below)

`PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\temp\C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Nagios - Schedule Downtime_lnk.ps1"`

(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2856739/you-cannot-use-a-symbolic-link-to-run-an-exe-file-or-execute-a-script)